# How To Use Grunt-Asset-Fingerprint To Refresh Cache

Tags: angularjs, caching, gruntjs

I am trying to get around an issue in my Angular website where when I add a page or make a change it does not show up to a user because of caching. Having done some reading I understand that what I want to do is to create a fingerprint.

I had a look around and it seemed like grunt-asset-fingerprint would do the trick. I have downloaded the package and tried to run it. However, I have two issues:

- It only seems to copy one file into the assets mapping file (infact it was my bing authorisation file), I would have thought it would copy all of them?
- I have no idea what to do next, do I need to add the fingerprint to the file names in order to avoid the caching problem? I could not find much documentation online.

Any help would be much appreciated! The relevant parts of my grunt config and the outputs of the assets.json file are below. Thanks!!

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
      
    assetFingerprint: {
      options: {
        algorithm: 'md5',
      },
      dist: {
        src: ["dist/**/*"],
        dest: "dist/"
      },
    }
      
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');  
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-processhtml');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-htmlmin');    
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-asset-fingerprint');
};
```

**assets.json**

```js
{
  "dist/": "./dist-dec2ce4621028dc1bd5g081ea11d1aff"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to successfully append the hash to my app.js file using this structure:

```
assetFingerprint: {
  "options": {
    "manifestPath": "dist/assets.json",
    "findAndReplaceFiles": [
        "index.html"
    ],
    "keepOriginalFiles": false
  },
  "dist": {
    "files": [
      {
        "expand": true,
        "cwd": "dist",
        "src": "app.js",
        "dest": "dist"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This will also update the reference to app.js in my index.html file. You have to make sure the paths used in the `files` block align with your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Refer grunt-rekai, this could solve file rename and have more options.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-rekai